# ¿Como sé qué versión de Django estoy usando?

Tags: python, django

Con frecuencia me pasa que necesito saber qué versión de Django estoy utilizando pero no consigo verlo de manera "rápida".

Como trabajo con un virtualenv, tiendo a utilizar `pip freeze | grep Django`. Sin embargo, hay veces en que dicho virtualenv no existe, por lo que sigo con la duda.

¿Cómo sé qué versión de Django está corriendo?

Comment: `pip freeze` no es un comando exclusivo de `virtualenv` y, por lo tanto, debería funcionar tanto dentro como fuera de cualquier ambiente virtual. Si después de utilizar `pip freeze | grep Django` no obtienes resultados significa simplemente que no está instalado.

Comment: @César cierto. Simplemente añadí algo de blabla para dar paso a la respuesta. En mi caso concreto la duda surge porque suelo tener distintos proyectos, cada uno con su virtualenv y diferentes versiones.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6468397/1983854

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay diferentes formas:

Abre la consola de Python y escribe:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

O bien:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
```

Directamente en la línea de comandos ejecuta:

```
python -m django --version
```

O incluso ejecuta una consola de Python con:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

Si tienes pip instalado:

```
pip freeze | grep Django

# o bien

pip show django
```

Directamente en la línea de comandos ejecuta:

```
django-admin --version
```